# Problems with CF9's EntityLoad()

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I've only just started out with CF9's ORM features, and have run into a problem.

I've got a single table set up - member - which has 2 records in it.

If I try:

```
<cfscript>
members = EntityLoad("member");
writedump(members);
</cfscript>
```

...I should get an array of member objects; but I get the error:

```
unexpected token: member near line 1, column 6 [from member]

The error occurred in \\vmware-host\Shared
Folders\Web\sites\testbed\webroot\orm\index.cfm: line 2
1 : ï»¿<cfscript>
2 : members = EntityLoad("member");
3 : writedump(members);
4 : </cfscript>
```

If I try:

```
<cfscript>
members = EntityLoad("member", {});
writedump(members);
</cfscript>
```

...I get the expected array of 2 member objects - but it takes 5-10 seconds to return it.

But if I request a unique object:

```
<cfscript>
members = EntityLoad("member", 1, true);
writedump(members);
</cfscript>
```

...I get the result returned instantaneously.

Any ideas as to what the problem(s) is/are?

**member.cfc**:

```
component output="false" persistent="true"
{
// identifier
property name="memberid" fieldtype="id"; 

// properties
property name="firstname";
property name="lastname";
property name="address1";
property name="address2";
property name="city";
property name="postcode";
property name="country";
property name="email";
property name="telephone";
property name="uuid";
property name="password";
}
```

Comment: The performance issue may just be an issue with my local dev environment - it goes at a decent speed on my production server. But the first error is still there on the production server...

Comment: can you post your member.cfc?

Comment: member.cfc added to original post. Yes, I'm running 9.0.1.

Comment: Seems for me as if your error is the result of a malformed UTF-8 mark at the beginning of index.cfm. Delete the file and recreate if from scratch. Maybe copying the code to a text only editor and saving it as index.cfm would be helpful.

Comment: Didn't fix it - see below... And the odd thing is that if I give the entityLoad() method more arguments, it works fine...

Comment: turn on ormsettings.logsql in application.cfc and see if there're any things weird going on?

Comment: OK, I'm probably being an idiot here, but I've turned on logSQL; where in Windows will the output go to?

Comment: %cf_path%\runtime\logs\#appName#-out.txt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out...

It turns out that "member" is a (semi-)reserved word in Hibernate: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1005886&start=0

Changing the object and table names to "sitemember" fixed the problem.

I would guess that it works fine if in the underlying HQL query there's a WHERE clause following the "SELECT FROM member"; but if you just have the basic entityload("member") then it doesn't have this WHERE clause.

I wonder if there are any other names I need to steer clear of?

Thanks for the help, Henry!